# Small android animation delay issue

Tags: android

I just want to call a function after every 3secs on click of a button
What is going wrong here-

```
 galleryBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
               for(int i = 0;i<3;i++){
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Do something after 5s = 5000ms
                        viewAnimator.showNext();
                   }
                }, 3000);
               } 
              }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually say what goes wrong but I'll take a wild guess that nothing happens (i.e. no animations) and the reason for that is probably that your Handler is being GC'd long before it gets to handle anything. Try keeping moving 'handlers' scope from local variable to class member.

(Also note that, even when it works, all 3 of your functions will run at more or less the same time. If you want them to run 3 seconds apart you should change the '3000' to 'i*3000'.)